# Javascript MVC like structure - how to create class structure

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript web app which I want to build based on the MVC-like principle.
My code works, but I'm struggling on how to do it right.
I am defining a global variable APP in which I place controllers, views, ...
Both methods work fine but the second function requires more code to achieve "the same" result.
I have read about IIFI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) but I don't really get the advantage over my first option.

Isn't it true that in the first option everything is also put in APP, so it can't pollute the global namespace? Or isn't option 1 not clean enough and should I use option 2?

Which are the advanages and disadvantages between the two methods?

Method 1:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var APP = APP || {};
APP.homecontroller = {
    index: function(){
        APP.hometemplate.show();
    }
}
APP.hometemplate = {
    show: function(){
        var x=document.getElementById("content");
        x.innerHTML = "index content";
    }
}
function init(){
    APP.homecontroller.index();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="init()">click to start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Method 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var APP = APP || {};
(function (APP) {
    APP.homecontroller = (function () {    
        function index() {
            APP.hometemplate.show();
        }
        return {
            index: index
        };
    }());
    APP.hometemplate = (function () {    
        function show() {
            var x=document.getElementById("content");
            x.innerHTML = "index content";
        }
        return {
            show: show
        };
    }());   
}(APP));

function init(){
    APP.homecontroller.index();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="init()">click to start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a framework IMO. Loads around, http://durandaljs.com/, http://aurelia.io/ or https://angularjs.org/

Looking at what you want to achieve and your code aurelia might be a good fit

Comment: It's pretty lightweight so I prefer to write something myself for that + for learning purposes :)

Comment: It always starts lightweight but then gets bigger, I don't see the point in re-inventing the wheel tbh.

Comment: Some framework is born every minute somewhere, keeping it simple and small isn't always that bad. But I don't need advice on that, but on the question please :

Comment: Both of your methods achieve the exact same thing, one is a bit more verbose with the IIFE. That's about it. Not sure why you have the 2 other IIFEs in the closure though, don't think they are needed.

Comment: Ok thx, about the other 2 IFFE's, I thought so too, but I got it from some tutorial, looks overkill.

Comment: Yeah, does a bit. IIFE overload :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you create `APP` object and define the public methods to this object. It doesn't necessary pollute the global namespace, since all members are wrapped inside `APP` but in my view it pollutes the `APP` context itself (more logic - more public functions for each). I don't know how big is the project going to be, but the second example gives you bigger robustness. It allows you to define private methods inside each "sub object".

Still, all layers of MVC should be separated and communicate using notifications.

You could create a module for each, since it's quite common that particular parts of MVC consists of more sub-mechanisms, for example for `Model` it could be `observers` which check for changes in `data` and invoke refresh to `view`

```
var Model = (function(){
    var data = [];

    var Observer = function(){
        // some internal definition..
        this.queue = []; 
    };

    var getData = function(){
        // some logic here
        return data;
    };

    var addData = function(object){
        data.push(object); 
    }

    return {
        addData: addData,
        getData: getData,
        getObserver: new Observer();
    }
})();
```

Similarlly with `View` which handles the presentation layer and expose a `refresh` functionality.

```
var Views = (function(){
    // whatever..
    var parts = [];

    var refresh = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
            // render view..
        }
    }

    return {
        refresh: refresh
    }
})();
```

..and `Controller` which would be just a "bridge" between `model` and `controller`.

Alternativelly, as your project grows, you could introduce a `namespaces` and perhaps some [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) framework to handle larger amounts of JS files. As I said, depends how big is your project really going to be..what should it be capable of etc. It all depends. Hope it helps you a bit.

Comment: Thx, it's a bit overkill for the desired requirements of my current project, but I will keep your interesting approach in mind.